# What is the realistic performance of live packet capture?

Tags: performance, packet-capture

I know it depends on the environment, but I would like to know the real live packet capture performance.

The questions are:

- What is the BPS (Bits per second) and PPS (Packet per second) do you process at the peak?
- What is the environment on the capturing side? (Linux, UNIX, Router, etc.)

Background:
We would like to create packet capturing system and expect a significant amount of data to come to that system. We want to know which HW/System spec is suitable for that system.